# taking default value in argparse

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using argparser module and when using the below two commands.
The first works fine, but the second one fails.

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I want if no value is specified it should take today as the value.

I am fetching the result using results.day

```
parser.add_argument('-sub4'  , action='store' , dest='subject4' , help='Fourth subject'              , type=str , default="")

parser.add_argument('-day'   , action='store' , dest='day'      , help="yesterday/week default-today , type=str , default="today")
```

Thanks

Comment: `help="yesterday/week default-today"` is missing a closing `"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing closing quote here:

```
p="yesterday/week default-today
```

Comment: oops ( how can i do that ),  thanks